# Angular Nativescript router shows incorrect page after login for few seconds

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am working on a native script angular app. when a user logs into  the app I authenticate the user from firebase and then check to see if the user has completed the registration process. If not the app navigates the user to the registration page, otherwise it sends the user to the main page.

I find that when a user who has not completed registration logs in the user is taken to the main page momentarily for 1 or 2 seconds and then redirected to the registration page. 
Any suggestions on why this happening and how I can fix it

( I would like users who have not registered to come directly to the registration page without going to the main page for a few seconds). I am using the [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/) for authentication.

My code is as follows:

app.routing.ts

```
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login.component"
import { RegistrationComponent } from "./registration/registration.component"
import {MainComponent, MainTabComponent,TabComponent} from          "./shared/maintab/maintab.component"
import {AuthGuard} from "./services/auth-guard.service"

export const AppRoutes:any =[
    { path: "login", component:LoginComponent },
    { path: "registration", component:RegistrationComponent},
    { path:"main", component:MainComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: "tab/0", component: UserFeedExampleComponent },
            { path: "tab/1", component: TabComponent }, 
             { path: "", redirectTo: "tab/0", pathMatch: "full" }
        ]
    },
    { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" }   
];

export const AppComponents: any = [
    MainTabComponent,
    MainComponent,
    TabComponent,
     LoginComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
];
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router/router-extensions';
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
import { FirebaseAuthService } from '../services/firebase-auth.service';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app-login",
    templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
    // changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class LoginComponent {
    user: User;
    isLoggingIn = true;
    isRegistering = false;
    isAuthenticating = false;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;


    constructor(private firebaseAuthService: FirebaseAuthService,
        private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions,
        private router: Router,
        private page: Page
    ) {
        page.actionBarHidden = true;
        this.user = new User("", "");
        this.firstname = "";
        this.lastname = "";
    }


    submit() {
        this.isAuthenticating = true;
        if (!this.isLoggingIn && !this.isRegistering) {
            this.login();
        } else {
            this.signUp();
        }
    }

    login() {
        this.firebaseAuthService.login(this.user)
            .then(() => {
                this.isAuthenticating = false;
                this.checkUserRegistration(this.user);
            })
            .catch((message: any) => {
                this.isAuthenticating = false;
            });
    }

    public onGoogleLoginTap() {
        var self = this;
        firebase.login({
            type: firebase.LoginType.GOOGLE
        }).then((result) => {

            self.saveUsertoDatabase();
            self.checkUserRegistration(result);

        }),
            function (errorMessage) {
                console.log(errorMessage);
            }
        console.log("login with google");
    };

    saveUsertoDatabase() {
        var self = this;
        firebase.getCurrentUser().then((user) => {
            firebase.update('/trial/' + user.uid, {
                email: user.email
            }).then(
                function (result) {
                    console.log("User uid: " + user.uid + "User email: " + user.email);
                }
                );
        }, (error) => {
            alert("Unable to get User: " + error);
        });
    }

    checkUserRegistration(result) {
        var self = this;
        var onQueryEvent = function (result) {
            if (!result.error) {
                if (!result.hasOwnProperty('registrationComplete')) {
                    self.goToRegistrationPage(self.user);
                }
                else {
                    self.gotoFeedPage();
                }
            }
        };

        firebase.query(
            onQueryEvent,
            ("/trial/" + result.uid),
            {
                singleEvent: true,
                orderBy: {
                    type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                    value: 'registrationComplete'
                },
            }
        );
    }


    goToRegistrationPage(user) {
        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: {
                registeredUser: JSON.stringify({ user })
            }
        };
        console.log("selected user is " + JSON.stringify({ user }));
        this.router.navigate(["registration"], navigationExtras);
    }

    toggleDisplay() {
        this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
    }

    toggleRegistration() {
        this.isRegistering = !this.isRegistering;
    }

    gotoFeedPage() {
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/main/tab/0"], { clearHistory: true });
    }


    logout() {
        this.firebaseAuthService.logout();
        console.log("Logged out")
        this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/login"], { clearHistory: true });
    }
}
```

Other details about the platform are as follows:

tns 2.5.0
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.18
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like you want your AuthGuard (your authentication guard) to do that registration check for you before returning. The AuthGuard can return an observable or promise that the router waits for in situations where the check is asynchronous. That's why the guard is allowed to return an observable or promise - to delay navigation until you are able to confirm whether to allow the navigation.

**Edit:**

To answer your specific question as to why the user sees the login page temporarily - if you follow your logic, your check to see if the user is registered is an asynchronous request to the Firebase API. Since it's asynchronous, after calling that `checkRegistration` function, the execution continues on and the user is routed into your app. Only after the firebase API returns a result does the navigation to your registration page occur.

Since you don't want that behaviour - you want to delay navigation until you complete all your checks - the recommendation is that you add all your checks to your navigation guards. If your navigation guard returns an asynchronous result (promise or observable), the router will wait until the asynchronous result completes before navigating.

Comment: Thanks for responding. You are right about the auth guard. What I am not able to understand is why  a user who has not registered is sent to the main component for a second and then redirected to the registration page as should be done by the registration check function below              if (!result.hasOwnProperty('registrationComplete')) {
                    self.goToRegistrationPage(self.user);
                }
                else {
                    self.gotoFeedPage();
                }

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Got it to work correctly by executing the navigation once the firebase query is executed.